# Pass vlookup result to array variable in vba

Tags: arrays, variables, excel, vlookup, vba

I've got a table that I named "LUT" on worksheet "LutSht" as below:

```
A   1   2   3
B   4   5   6
C   7   8   9
```

In a second worksheet "CalSht" cell A1 contains a dropdown list generated from the first column of "LUT"

When I record a macro to get an idea of how vlookup operates in VBA, it produces:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],LUT,2,)"
```

In this instance the looked up value gets written to a cell. I am trying to pass it to an array variable instead.

Here is my flawed code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim x(3) As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        For i = 1 To 3
            x(i)=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],LUT,i+1,) 
'Line kept simple, but myriad of alternatives were tested unsuccessfully 
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

All my attempts to correct the syntax failed so far. Can you help please?

Comment: Is "LUT" a sheet or a range? In you're current code LUT isn't anything

Comment: @scott, according to the question, it's a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming LUT is a named range:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim arrResults() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    If Not Intersect(Me.Range("A1"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        ReDim arrResults(1 To [COLUMNS(LUT)] - 1)
        For i = 1 To UBound(arrResults)
            arrResults(i) = Evaluate("VLOOKUP(A1,LUT," & i + 1 & ",TRUE)")
        Next i

        'Do something with your array here
        MsgBox Join(arrResults, ", ")

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As Scott points out, you haven't initialized your `Table/ListObject` variable. This is untested, but I think it will work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim loLUT as Excel.ListObject
    Dim x(3) As Double
    Dim i As Integer

    Set loLUT = me.ListObjects("LUT")
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        For i = 1 To 3
            x(i)=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],LUT,i+1,) 
'Line kept simple, but myriad of alternatives were tested unsuccessfully 
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Remember to use `Option Explicit` to force yourself to declare variables.